# Is NextAuth Credentials safe?

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I use `next-auth` [Credentials](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/configuration/providers#credentials-provider) (v3) to allow my users to register and sign in with good old email and password in my NextJS website. I use MongoDB as my database.

This is my `[...nextauth].js` file:

```
export default NextAuth({
  session: {
    jwt: true
  },
  providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        await dbConnect();

        // Check if a user with the email exists
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: credentials.email });
        if (!user) throw new Error("Emailen is not in use");

        // Check if the password is correct
        const correctPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password
        );
        if (!correctPassword) throw new Error("Wrong password");

        return {
          userid: user._id,
          email: user.email,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    // Add userid to token
    async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.userid;
      }
      return token
    },
    // Add userid to session returned to front-end
    async session(session, token) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      return session
    }
  }
});
```

Before fetching data in my NextJS API endpoints, I check if the user is authenticated like this:

```
const session = await getSession({ req });
const user = await UserModel.findById(session?.user?.id);

if (!session || !user)
  return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
```

But I'm worried that if a person gets the id of another user, they can just edit their JWT `session.user.id` and access any API endpoint pretending to be another user?

Is that true? Would the users be able to fake their id's in my code?

If so, what can I do to avoid that?